# How pass variable to JSON value?

Tags: c#, json

I want to pass variable into JSON value, something like usual concat for string.

I am learning c# now, so that is why I am asking

For instance, in python it looks like this:

```
{      
      "path_to_file": "/Users/%(user_name)s/path/"
}
```

And using in script:

```
rendered = json.loads(file.read() % {"user_name": my_user_name})
```

Can you explain me how to do the same but in c#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest *not* treating the JSON as a string - instead, use a JSON library to build the JSON. That way you don't need to worry about escaping etc.

Comment: Where are you getting this json from , and then what are you doing with it

Comment: It is my JSON, configuration file.

Comment: If you are not sending this over the wire. just deserailize using any json library. https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+deserialize+json+in+c%23&oq=how+to+deersialise+json+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i13i457j0i13l5.5691j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8